# How to align VerticalPager page with pager indicators?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, viewpagerindicator

Pager indicator and pager are in two separate libraries. I've been unable to get the indicators to sit to the right of the page.

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun Photos(photos: List<String>){
    val state = rememberPagerState()
    Row{
        VerticalPager(count = photos.size, state = state, contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 32.dp)) {
            AsyncImage(model = photos[it], contentDescription = null, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
        }
        VerticalPagerIndicator(pagerState = state)
    }
}
```

I've tried setting a custom width for the AsyncImage but it's not giving me what I'm expecting which is enough space for the indicator to sit horizontally next to the page.

Comment: Can you post some screenshot of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Set verticalAlignment to Alignment.CenterVertically, it's Alignment.Top by default

```
Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
){
    VerticalPager(count = photos.size, state = state, contentPadding = PaddingValues(vertical = 32.dp)) {
        AsyncImage(model = photos[it], contentDescription = null, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())
    }
    VerticalPagerIndicator(pagerState = state)
}
```

Comment: There is no indicator. It disappeared. I even changed the asyncimage maxsize to 300dp and it still didn't work.